# Registration in Drupal Sites

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-6, module

I am making a drupal [site](http://nssiitd.co.cc) and have a custom content type Event. I want user be able to register themselves at the event page. For this there is a module namely [Event Manager](http://drupal.org/project/event_manager) . But this module is not present Drupal 6.x [release](http://drupal.org/node/228538/release). Is there some other workaround of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module way:

use following modules (still in development but it should do the trick)

[event module](http://drupal.org/project/event)

[signup module](http://drupal.org/project/signup)

(this will create an event content type for you, don't forget to set the permissions)

Go to the content type edit screen (content type -> event -> edit)

Set the Signup configuration section default to enabled or installed.

---

Using your own content type:

In your node-event.tpl.php you can check if a teaser or the full node is loaded.

```
if($teaser){ /*here teaser code*/ }else{ /*here full node code*/ }
```

At the bottom of the full node code you can put a php form that inserts data in a custom table in the database and send a mail to an address. You can create your own module to retrieve the data then and show it in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Another module way is to use the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) and possible [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) modules instead of Event. Calendar is only needed if you need *classic* calendar view of your event. Date is stable, uses CCK and should be available for Drupal 7 soon after its release. Ensuring a smooth upgrade path for the future. The [Signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) module is compatible with Date and should provides the wanted feature.